# how to uncheck all other nodes after check one node which are all on same top level?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I did once successfully but somehow lost original code, since I'm not expert in jstree so your help is very much appreciated, below is my attempt:

```
    .on("select_node.jstree", (e, data) => {
      const node = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true);
      if (!node) {
        return;
      }
      if (node[0].ariaLevel == "1" && node[0].ariaSelected == "true") {
        const siblings = node.siblings;
        if (siblings.length > 0)
          siblings(".selected").each(function () {
            data.instance.check_node(this, 0);
          });
      }
    })
```

runs OK until when i try to loop siblings and uncheck, can anyone help me on below code:   siblings(".selected").each(function () {
data.instance.check_node(this, 0);
});

Answer (score 0):

figured out, paste code here in case someone needs reference or give me comment to optimize it, thanks.

```
    .on("select_node.jstree", async (e, data) => {
      var level = data.node.parents.length;
      var selected = data.node.state.selected;
      var text = data.node.text; // for info only
      var id = data.node.id;
      if (level == 1 && selected) {
        var tree = $(this.treeContainer).jstree(),
          parent = tree.get_node(data.node.parent),
          children = parent.children,
          siblings = [];
        children.forEach(function (child) {
          if (child !== id) siblings.push(child);
        });
        siblings.forEach(function (sibling) {
          var sNode = tree.get_node(sibling);
          if (sNode.state.selected) {
            tree.uncheck_node(sNode);
          }
        });
      }
    })
```